# Recursively execute Linux 'ar' command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a directory with hundreds of sub-directories with many .lib files in them. I am able to use the `ar -x filename.lib` command to unpack one of them, but I was wondering how one would do this recursively since there is no built in recursive flag according to `man ar`. Right now I am trying to do

```
find . -name '*.lib' -exec ar -x {} +
```

but I get a message saying for every file `no entry filename.lib in archive`. I googled this error but I could not find anything relevant, and my current method of doing it is based off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively) question's answers (namely the 2nd one and its comments), but clearly it is not working. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Meta-note: there is no such thing as "the 2nd answer". Any user can order answers by "votes", "oldest" or "active" on their own; votes change, activity gets updated…

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski my bad, fixed the question and was referring to 2nd one by votes, which because the question is old will probably be the second answer for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`man 1 ar`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) says the syntax is

```
ar [--plugin name] [-X32_64] [-]p[mod [relpos] [count]] archive [member...]
```

So it works with one archive at a time, the extra arguments are members. You obviously don't want to specify members.

`find … -exec … {} +` substitutes `{}` with *mutliple* paths. Excessive paths are interpreted as members by `ar`. You need `find … -exec … {} … \;` which subsitutes `{}` with just one path.

```
find . -name '*.lib' -exec ar -x {} \;
```

This way every file found is passed to a *separate* `ar` and satisfies its requirement for just one archive.

Note: `-execdir` may or may not be better for you. Refer to [`man 1 find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to learn the difference.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the detailed and quick answer. I'm also glad to know that my original answer wasn't too far off.